# fastest way to tell if a term exists in the index or not

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the fastest query that can tell if a term exists in the index or not. I am not looking for scoring or anything, just a quick true/false response form elastic search that it has a document that contains this index.

Comment: This can help you if you intend to search from all the fields in an index. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Comment: this will make the index bigger in size, you can instead use multi_match query to 
 query multiple fields and use type = cross_fields to treat all of them as one.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `_count`  API.

example:

```
GET /twitter/_count?q=user:kimchy
```

more information:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

also you can set the size to 0:

```
 GET /twitter/user/_search {
    "size": 0,   
    "query": {
             "match": {  
                     "username": "xyz" 
}}}
```